# Notification.requestPermission() não funciona no navegador Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Tenho o seguinte código Java Script em meu sistema

```
<script>
function showNotification(mensagem){
  const notification = new Notification('Teste Notificação',{
  body: mensagem,
  icon: 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/20/79/03/2079033abc8314be554f9d24f562a199.jpg'
  })
}
console.log(Notification.permission)
if(Notification.permission==='granted'){
  showNotification('Você possui notificações não lidas.');
}else if(Notification.permission!=="denied"){
  Notification.requestPermission().then(permission=>{
    if(permission ==='granted'){
        showNotification('Você possui notificações não lidas.');
    }
  })
}
</script>
```

No Navegador Chrome e Edge e Opera funcionam 100%

Já no Navegador FireFox apresenta a seguinte mensagem no console

> A permissão para notificação só deve ser requisitada a partir de um
> manipulador de eventos de curta duração gerado pelo usuário.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso ocorre especificamente no Firefox pois em [Abril de 2019](https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2019/04/01/reducing-notification-permission-prompt-spam-in-firefox/) já haviam decidido mudar a forma que o `Notification.requestPermission` se comporta, o motivo dessa decisão foi para reduzir o numero de janelas de prompt solicitando permissão, pois esse recurso estava sendo **muito mal usado** pelos desenvolvedores, tornando isso em um tipo de SPAM.

[Em Novembro do mesmo ano, a partir da versão 72 do Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2019/11/04/restricting-notification-permission-prompts-in-firefox/) isso passou a ser padrão como bloqueado.

No entanto pode notar que o ícone de notificação fica animado quando é solicitado a permissão, ele só não exibe o popup/prompt, para exibir o usuário deve clicar no ícone por vontade própria e decidir ativar ou bloquear:

> [image: ativar notificação no Firefox]
>
> *Fonte da imagem: https://blog.mozilla.org*

Se me permitem expor minha opinião, essa forma que o Firefox atua é bem mais agradável ao usuário final, pois muitos sites que visitamos eventualmente ficavam perturbando, se tantos desenvolvedores não fizessem mau uso de tantas coisas talvez muitas decisões e bloqueios hoje não existiriam.

Voltando ao foco da pergunta, além de clicar no ícone (localizado na barra de endereços) para exibir a solicitação de permissão, você também pode ativar o `Notification.requestPermission()` através de uma interação com o usuário usando o evento `click`. Note que os navegadores sabem quando o evento `click` foi disparado pelo usuário e quando foi disparado por uma "simulação", exemplo [`HTMLElement.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click), se tentar simular também **não** vai funcionar.

Um exemplo que vai funcionar:

```html
<button onclick="ativarNotificacoes()">Ativar notificações</button>

<script>
function ativarNotificacoes() {
    Notification.requestPermission();
}
</script>
```

> [image: solicitar permissão para notificações no Firefox]

---

Qualquer tentativa de simular o click irá falhar, como no exemplo a seguir:

```html
<button onclick="ativarNotificacoes()" id="simular">Ativar notificações</button>

<script>
document.getElementById("simular").click();

function ativarNotificacoes() {
    Notification.requestPermission();
}
</script>
```

Apresentando no console o erro:

> A permissão para notificação só deve ser requisitada a partir de um manipulador de eventos de curta duração gerado pelo usuário.

Em navegadores configurados em inglês:

> The Notification permission may only be requested from inside a short running user-generated event handler.